# Выбор из нескольких листов Excel c помощью Transact-SQL

Tags: sql-server, excel

Подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом можно импортировать данные одного и того же столбца по всем листам файла Excel?

На данный момент научилась делать так:

```
SELECT DISTINCT col2 FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
     'Excel 12.0; Database=D:\probn.xlsx','SELECT * FROM 
 [B2:B40]');
GO
```

Но так ищет только по первому листу.

Comment: Вроде такой синтаксис **SELECT * FROM [Sheet2$B2:B40]**, чтобы выбрать данные с другого листа

Comment: Да, но мне надо, чтобы со всех вторых колонок нашел различные значения. Либо может как-то их названия получить и перебором сделать.

Comment: Если неизвестны названия листов воспользуйтесь поиском листов, подставляя нужные значения для ячеек. Например [так](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/openrowset-when-excel-worksheet-name-is-unknown).

Comment: То есть лучше создать связанный сервер?

Comment: не понял причем здесь связанный сервер? Откуда это требования появляется?!

Comment: Тогда можно воспользоваться sp_tables_ex.

Comment: В примере-то автор, я так понимаю, как параметр, название листа передает. У меня на входе в процедуру должен быть лишь путь к файлу. Поэтому сколько там листов и их названия, я не знаю.